# How to use Vuex types constants with module namespace?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have this Vuex module:

```
//modules/things.js
const state = {
  firstThing: 'abc',
  secondThing: 'def',
};

const getters = {
  getFirstThing: state => state.firstThing,
  getSecondThing: state => state.secondThing,
};

const mutations = {
  setFirstThing: (state, payload) => state.firstThing = payload,
  setSecondThing: (state, payload) => state.secondThing = payload
};

const actions = {};

export default {
  namespaced: true,   // <------
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
};
```

I use `namespaced: true` [flag](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#namespacing) and can work with this module like this:

```
this.$store.state.things.firstThing             // <-- return abc here
this.$store.commit('things/setFirstThing', 10)
this.$store.getters['things/getFirstThing']     // <-- return abc here
```

If I will use constants like in Vuex [official example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/shopping-cart/store/mutation-types.js), and refactor my `modules/things.js` file like this:

```
export const Types = {
  getters: {
    GET_FIRST_THING: 'GET_FIRST_THING',
    GET_SECOND_THING: 'GET_SECOND_THING',
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_FIRST_THING: 'SET_FIRST_THING',
    SET_SECOND_THING: 'SET_SECOND_THING',
  }
};

const getters = {
  [Types.getters.GET_FIRST_THING]: state => state.firstThing,
  [Types.getters.GET_SECOND_THING]: state => state.secondThing,
};

const mutations = {
  [Types.mutations.SET_FIRST_THING]: (state, payload) => state.firstThing = payload,
  [Types.mutations.SET_SECOND_THING]: (state, payload) => state.secondThing = payload
};
```

I will have to use namespace prefix:

```
this.$store.commit('things/' + Types.mutations.SET_FIRST_THING, 10);
this.$store.getters['things/' +  + Types.getters.GET_FIRST_THING]
```

If I will include module namespace prefix to `Types` constant, I will have to use string prefix `things/` for mutations/actions/getters declaration:

```
const getters = {
  ['things/' + Types.getters.GET_FIRST_THING]: state => state.firstThing,
  ['things/' + Types.getters.GET_SECOND_THING]: state => state.secondThing,
};
```

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can disable namespacing by `namespaced: false` and just use constants with prefixes:

```
export const Types = {
  getters: {
    GET_FIRST_THING: 'THINGS_GET_FIRST_THING',    // your namespace without '/' slash
    GET_SECOND_THING: 'THINGS_GET_SECOND_THING',
  },
  // ...
}
```

- it will work.

But if you still want to keep `namespaced: true` in module and use constants also, you can define two types of constants: **public** and **private**:

```
export const Types = {                                               // <-- public
  getters: {
    GET_FIRST_THING: 'things/GET_FIRST_THING',
    GET_SECOND_THING: 'things/GET_SECOND_THING',
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_FIRST_THING: 'things/SET_FIRST_THING',
    SET_SECOND_THING: 'things/SET_SECOND_THING',
  }
};

const _types = removeNamespace('things/', Types);                    // <-- private
```

Then use private `_types` only inside Vuex module:

```
const getters = {
  [_types.getters.GET_FIRST_THING]: state => state.firstThing,       
  [_types.getters.GET_SECOND_THING]: state => state.secondThing,
};

//...
```

and public `Types` outside module:

```
// some-component.vue
this.$store.commit(Types.mutations.SET_FIRST_THING, 10);
this.$store.getters[Types.getters.GET_FIRST_THING]
// ...
```

Also implement simple `removeNamespace` function in your new `namespace-helper.js` file:

```
export default function removeNamespace(namespace, types){
  return _.reduce(types, (typeObj, typeValue, typeName) => {
    typeObj[typeName] = _.reduce(typeValue, (obj, v, k)=>{
      obj[k] = v.replace(namespace, '');
      return obj;
    }, {});
    return typeObj;
  }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646215/1360592) from @hedin worked brilliantly for me, thank you!

The only issues I had were:

1. I'm using Typescript.
2. It could be a bit overly verbose, hurting readability. However type safety is more important to me, and I'm willing to tolerate some verbosity get type checking.

Inspired by his design, I Typescripted it and reduced the verbosity.

(I am using Vue 3 (with composition API) + Vuex 4 (with namespaced modules).)

Firstly, I created `namespace-helper.ts` that looks like this:

```
import _ from "lodash";

type NamespaceHelper = {
  [name: string]: string;
};

// Enhanced from @hedin, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646215/1360592
export default (
  namespace: string,
  types: any,
  section: "getters" | "actions" | "mutations",
): NamespaceHelper => {
  return _.reduce(
    types,
    (typeObj: NamespaceHelper, typeValue, typeName) => {
      if (typeName === section) {
        return _.reduce(
          typeValue,
          (obj: NamespaceHelper, v, k) => {
            obj[k] = v.replace(namespace, "");
            return obj;
          },
          {},
        );
      }
      return typeObj;
    },
    {},
  );
};
```

Then in my store module, I have:

```
const namespace = "things";

// For external use
export const Types = {
  getters: {
    GET_FIRST_THING: `${namespace}/GET_FIRST_THING`,
    GET_SECOND_THING: `${namespace}/GET_SECOND_THING`,
  },
  actions: {
    DO_FIRST_THING: `${namespace}/DO_FIRST_THING`,
    DO_SECOND_THING: `${namespace}/DO_SECOND_THING`,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_FIRST_THING: `${namespace}/SET_FIRST_THING`,
    SET_SECOND_THING: `${namespace}/SET_SECOND_THING`,
  },
};

// For internal use in the same store
const _getters = removeNamespace(`${namespace}/`, Types, "getters");
const _actions = removeNamespace(`${namespace}/`, Types, "actions");
const _mutations = removeNamespace(`${namespace}/`, Types, "mutations");

// getters
const getters: GetterTree<MyStoreState, RootState> = {
  [_getters. GET_FIRST_THING]: (state) => {
    return state.blah;
  },
  ...
};

// actions
const actions: ActionTree<MyStoreState, RootState> = {
  [_actions.DO_FIRST_THING]: ({ commit }) => {
    // do stuff here
    ...
    commit(_mutations.SET_FIRST_THING);
  },
};

// mutations
const mutations = {
  [_mutations.SET_FIRST_THING]: (state: MyStoreState) => {
    state.blah = "foo";
  },
};

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

And here is how I use it from a component:

```
<script lang="ts">
// imports go here, not shown for brevity

import { Types } from "@/store/modules/things";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Thing",
  setup(props) {
    const store = useStore<RootState>();

    // I prefer singular for consuming getters and actions externally.
    const { getters: getter, actions: action } = Types;

    const firstThing = computed<ThingType>(() =>
      store.getters[getter.GET_FIRST_THING],
    );

    store.dispatch(action.DO_FIRST_THING);

    return {
      firstThing,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I needed to add `import removeNamespace from '../namespace-helper'` in the store but then _actions is of NamespaceHelper type and doesn't have _getter or the other properties.