# Vuex combining namespaced modules and constants types

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

i always use constants types for vuex eg.

```
const SET_CATEGORY = 'setCategory'
```

but now i want to use modules with namespace and im stuck, should i change names (for example for module 'game') to

`const SET_CATEGORY = 'game/setCategory'` ?

When im doing this, my mutation looks `'game/game/setCategory'`.

I know why it looks like that (becouse i use same constants types to create and call mutation) but don't know how deal with it.

I can just call mutations like
`store.commit('game/${SET_CATEGORY}')` but thats doesnt look good.

ps.Sorry for mistakes, im not native.

Cheers

Comment: There is an excellent explanation in this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646176/how-to-use-vuex-types-constants-with-module-namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using namespaces you don't need to change your mutation and action names. So:

```
const SET_CATEGORY = 'setCategory' //stays the same
```

And as you correctly put, to reference this mutation in a module named 'game:

```
store.commit(`game/${SET_CATEGORY}`);
```

or

```
const moduleName = 'game';
store.commit(`${moduleName}/${SET_CATEGORY}`);
```